# How do I show CloudWatch stats per server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have some metrics that are being published to CloudWatch logs.
(It would probably be better as CloudWatch metrics)

Basic Query:

```
fields @timestamp, jvm.threads.live, process.cpu.usage, server , system.load.average.1m , jvm.memory.usage.after.gc
| sort by @timestamp desc
```

[image: Sample data]

Sample data json:

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2022-xx-xxT11:03:00.027Z",
    "jvm.gc.overhead": "0",
    "jvm.memory.usage.after.gc": "0.036",
    "jvm.threads.live": "47",
    "process.cpu.usage": "1",
    "server": "MyServer.localdomain",
    "system.load.average.1m": "2.351"
}
```

I can draw a graph using the below, but it does not take the `server` into account and it just averages all servers.

The server names are random, so I don't have a list of them upfront.

```
fields @timestamp, jvm.threads.live, process.cpu.usage, server , system.load.average.1m , jvm.memory.usage.after.gc
| stats avg(jvm.threads.live) as threads, avg(process.cpu.usage * 100) as cpuPercentage, avg(system.load.average.1m) as loadAvg, avg(jvm.memory.usage.after.gc * 100) as memoryPercentage  by bin(1m)
```

How do I show each server's stats and not just an average of all servers as below?

[image: stats for all servers]

Comment: Can you provide the log content in your question?

Comment: thanks @Paolo, I added a single record example in json.

Comment: `by server, bin(1m)` gives a query result, but I am unable to run a visualisation on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may work

```
fields @timestamp, jvm.threads.live, process.cpu.usage, server , system.load.average.1m , jvm.memory.usage.after.gc
| stats avg(jvm.threads.live) as threads, avg(process.cpu.usage * 100) as cpuPercentage, avg(system.load.average.1m) as loadAvg, avg(jvm.memory.usage.after.gc * 100) as memoryPercentage  by server, bin(1m)
```

Comment: sorry did not see your new comment, i would say you may have to transorm your logs to metrics using a metric-filter, you can reference all your values in the logs using ${.fielname} convention. You may need to create multiple metrics per field and set the dimension to the server name

Comment: thanks, how would do that? I have not worked with a metrics filter before

Comment: on aws console , go to ctoudwatch-> log groups -> select your log group -> actions -> create metric filter

check 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringLogData.html
and 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html

Comment: The answer actually visualises as a bar chart, but not a line chart